# Windows 7 installation without boot loader

Tags: windows, installation, boot

I have a Windows 7 installation that doesn't have a boot loader on the disk.
Basically, the story goes;
I had two disks on my PC where one of them served as the system disk with Windows 7 installed, and then a storage disk. The system disk was starting to present some disturbing errors and mystical freeze lags, so I decided to get a new disk to serve as the system disk. 
When I then installed Windows 7 on the new disk, I was planning on keeping the faulty disk as it was still spinning, but forgot to disconnect it during the new installation. I'm guessing this is why the installer never created a boot loader partition on my new disk automatically.
As long as my old system disk is running, I'm able to boot into my new installation (I get two options in the boot loader menu), but now it's failing more and more, and I need two or three reboots in order to even get to the boot loader menu.

So, the question is; is there any way to install a boot loader to my new system disk without wiping it? I'm guessing the installation starts at the first sector, and blocks the ability to use boot sect (I've tried, and it fails saying it can't install on this disk).

I'm willing to try other boot loaders, but I have a feeling it doesn't really matter, so I'm just putting the question out there in case there are any geniuses there that want to show their skills!

Answer (score 1):

Start from your Windows 7 media or recovery disk

Select your input options

Repair

System Recovery Options > Command Prompt

```
bootrec /fixmbr  
bootrec /fixboot  
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

You may also be able to fix it using VisualBCD Editor by using the "Creating missing Windows Loaders" option

http://www.boyans.net/